# Cannot get git clone to work properly

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have followed the instructions here [Cannot push to git repository on bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074832/cannot-push-to-git-repository-on-bitbucket)

When I run `ssh-add -l` I receive the correct information, and I have added my public ssh-key to bitbucket.

However, every time I run git clone I receive:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.

Any help?

Comment: what is the remote URL that you are using? Did you make sure to use the correct user?

Comment: Figured it out, answer below! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, right after I asked it. I did not have the proper write permissions to the director I was in. Therefore I was having to use `sudo git`.

`sudo` was not properly setup for ssh, my account was.

After fixing permissions in the folder using `chmod` and some suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376035/fatal-could-not-create-work-tree-dir-kivy), I was able to get `git` to work