# fatal: could not create work tree dir 'hello': Permission denied

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am new at using Git and GitHub and I keep getting this error

`fatal: could not create work tree dir 'hello': Permission denied`

That's the message I get when I use git clone on my windows terminal. I also tried it on the Git Bash terminal and I still get the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fatal: could not create work tree dir 'kivy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376035/fatal-could-not-create-work-tree-dir-kivy)

Comment: Question is relevant to me, and probably others too.  Why the downvote?  What is people's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal probably doesn't have the right permissions. Did you try opening the terminal as administrator?

Comment: how do I do that? Sorry am new at using the terminal

Comment: right-click on the terminal and you should see a 'Run as Administrator' button.

Just as you see in [this](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwinaero.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F12%2FWindows-10-Run-as-administrator2.png&f=1&nofb=1) image.

Comment: ok I think that might work, am going to give it a try. Is there a way to always open the terminal as an admin?

Comment: [This](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/always-run-a-program-in-administrator-mode-in-windows-10/) tutorial should do the trick.

Comment: @ciurca this is probably better suited as a comment instead of an answer. Avoid one line answers that ask questions within them... instead use comments for that

Answer (score 0):

1. First create a central (remote) repository in GitHub. Git recommends that for every project you need to maintain a unique repository. I.e one repository for one project.
2. Next create local repository in the local machine. Open GitBash at the required directory and type `git init`. (If you have to create a new folder please do so.).
3. After we create our local repository it is very important to link/ sync them. Otherwise how would you know which repository to push into or which remote repository to pull from. Run the following command in the git bash `git remote add origin <LinkFromRemoteRepo>`.